# Show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (order\ {S_n})q^n=\prod_{m\ge 1}(1-q^m)^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $T=\mathbb (C^*)^2$ acts on $\mathbb C[x,y]$ via $(t_1,t_2)(x,y)=(t_1x,t_2y)$, let $S_n$ be the set of ideals $I$ of $\mathbb C[x,y]$ such that $TI=I$ and $\mathbb C[x,y]/I$ is $n$-dimensional $\mathbb C$-vector space. If $order\ S_{0}=0$. show that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (order\ {S_n})q^n=\prod_{m\ge 1}(1-q^m)^{-1}.$$

Comment: how are $(t_1,t_2)$ coordinates on $\mathbb C^\ast$? you probably mean something slightly different.

Comment: I'm sorry and I have corrected it

Comment: +1 This is an excellent question, where is it from?

Comment: @mt_,someone gave to me and I don't have any ideas so I have to put it on here,do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this looks like a homework problem let me just give an outline.

1. Prove that an ideal is invariant under the torus action if and only if it is generated by monomials.
2. Prove that monomial ideals $I \subset \mathbb C[x,y]$ can be identified with [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29). Hint: draw a square grid with squares $(i,j)_{i \geq 0, j \geq 0}$. Mark each square $(i,j)$ such that $x^i y^j \in I$ with a different color. What kind of shape do you get?
3. Apply Euler's generating function for partitions.